Unity Application crashing on Android?
I've been working on an application in Unity. It works perfectly fine for iOS devices but once a build has been put onto an Android device it begins crashing after about a day of being on that device. Based on when the crashes happen, I assume it has something to do with SignalR. My only other lead is that Unity is using a deprecated version while our backend sends using an up to date version. I can provide the stack trace, but I honestly need some help debugging Android.
Like stated, it works perfectly fine on iOS. Expected the results to be the same. But I have no idea why its crashing after a day.
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x00000000000ae7ac  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000a37074  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000a375f0  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #03  pc 0x000000000087eebc  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000ac0b24  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000ac2a68  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000ac2e0c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #07  pc 0x000000000034402c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #08  pc 0x0000000003d09b10  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #09  pc 0x0000000001bc1c88  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #10  pc 0x0000000001bc1bd4  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #11  pc 0x000000000052f504  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #12  pc 0x000000000053e60c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #13  pc 0x0000000000540c0c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #14  pc 0x0000000000589f7c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #15  pc 0x000000000054dd80  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #16  pc 0x000000000054e190  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #17  pc 0x000000000054dcec  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #18  pc 0x000000000058bab0  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #19  pc 0x000000000058b984  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #20  pc 0x00000000003c1ffc  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #21  pc 0x00000000003c27ec  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #22  pc 0x000000000034ef20  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: d30ac65ad21d15e2)
  #23  pc 0x0000000003d99488  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #24  pc 0x000000000212fba8  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #25  pc 0x0000000001d1e568  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #26  pc 0x000000000201915c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #27  pc 0x0000000001d1ab70  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #28  pc 0x00000000030766f0  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #29  pc 0x000000000306d9b8  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #30  pc 0x0000000001ffb898  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #31  pc 0x000000000305c6b8  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #32  pc 0x00000000030731b4  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #33  pc 0x000000000345c14c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #34  pc 0x0000000003300f70  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #35  pc 0x000000000346c360  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #36  pc 0x000000000345c14c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #37  pc 0x000000000346c740  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #38  pc 0x000000000346c604  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #39  pc 0x0000000003460c98  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #40  pc 0x0000000001af3484  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #41  pc 0x0000000001bc1d0c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #42  pc 0x0000000001c0c4b8  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #43  pc 0x0000000001c29a3c  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #44  pc 0x0000000001c2d2dc  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #45  pc 0x0000000001b9a408  /data/app/~~H8IEfiGO_duThcByi7VD6w==/com.KFLOE.Tediddle-lRUs5uAmceWpT9DS8Vm9EQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: cb4c98218a7b7b5b)
  #46  pc 0x00000000000c37b4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+208)
  #47  pc 0x000000000005d084  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+68)


Sounds like a memory leak. One might assume that IOS is using default behaviour that works; while Android does not.  In hindsight, one should incrementally develop on all platforms one intends to target.

If you think this problem is related to SignalR, then we can enable asp.net core signalr server logging to view detailed messages. Then we may found some logs when the client app crash if the issue is related to SignalR.
